# Depth first search algorithm in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, depth-first-search

(This question is followed up in more detail here: [python-search-algorithm-from-implied-graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156834/python-search-algorithm-from-implied-graphs))

Suppose I have a function that takes an input ($x_i$) and then goes through a loop and yields a series of outputs ($x_{i, j}$). Then each output can be an input again to the same function yielding further outputs ($x_{i, j, k}$). And I'm trying to find a set of steps via this function to a particular end state.

This is a general problem, and my question is what is a good code structure within python to handle this.

Here's some meta code as an example (though it might be more complicated in practice):

```
def f(x):
  for i in range(n):
    if some_condition:
      yield g(x,i) 
  yield false
```

Then for some $x_0$ and some $y$, we're looking for a sequence $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_k$, such that $x_k=y$, and $x_{j+1}=g(x_j,i_j)$ for $j\in{0,\ldots,k-1}$.

To do this with a depth first search where you would calculate $f(f(\ldots f(x) \ldots))$ first until it yields the targeted result or a false. Then back up one step and yield the second result from $f$ and repeat (a rough description, but you get the idea: a depth first search, basically).

It seems to me that the yield keyword is going to be inefficient to handle this. You've also got to handle the stack (I think this is the right terminology) of $(x, f(x), f(f(x)),\ldots)$ in a way that allows you to back track when you hit a dead end.

This general problem is something I come across now and then, and I kind of solve it *ad hoc*, but I wondered if there was a good general structure for solving this, which naturally and efficiently handles the stack and exploring the tree of possible solutions in python.

I hope this question is sufficiently clear. I welcome any thoughts, comments, clarifications or answers.

Comment: What specifically makes you think that the problem can be done more efficiently than brute-forcing? Do you sometimes hit a point that you've already been before (maybe look at dynamic programming/memoizing in that case), or is each path unique? You probably need to provide a specific example and point out where your existing solution is inefficient.

Comment: I'm not expecting it to be faster than brute force. I'm just trying to find an efficient way to do the brute force in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that just using an explicit stack for the current path and recursion is simpler:

```
def search(start_state, neighbors, goal):
    path = [start_state]

    class PathFound(RuntimeError):
        pass

    def rsearch(x):
        if goal(x):
            raise PathFound
        for y in neighbors(x):
            path.append(y)
            rsearch(y)
            path.pop()

    try:
        rsearch(start_state)
    except PathFound:
        return path

    return None # No path exists
```

Python has a low recursion limit but for a depth-first search this is normally not an issue (and it can be extended anyway by `sys.setrecursionlimit`).

Comment: Is the indenting correct? I've not seen classes and functions be part of a function before?

Comment: @DrXorile: Yes. In Python you can declare classes and function inside functions. They will simply be local to the function.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks very much. +1 now, and a tick after I've tested it!

Comment: So goal and neighbors are functions of any given state, right.  And then you just call search to solve the problem

Comment: @DrXorile: exactly. The exception trick is used to bail out of all the nested calls when (if) we get to the goal.

Comment: Clever!  And if there might be more than one solution, so we just want to spit it out and then carry on, is it as simple as yielding the path, or do we need more

Comment: I've adapted some code, and I'm running it now, so I'll see how it goes!

Comment: One additional problem I'm coming across is that one of the outputs in neighbors(x) is the parent, so I end up getting a loop back and forth.  I don't know if it's easier to fix the neighbors function or the search function...

Comment: @Dr Xorile: if the same state cannot be visited more than once you could add a check in the search function to ignore alteady visited states...

Comment: I added in a line saying "if y in path: continue" just after the "for y in neighbors(x)". It's a problem of having an undirected graph implied by neighbors,  vs a directed one...

Answer (score 2):

```
class Tree:
def __init__(self, value, children = None):
    self.value = value
    self.children = []
    if children:
        self.children = list(children)

def get_children(self):
    return list(self.children)

def get_value(self):
    return self.value

def has_children(self):
    if self.children:
        return True

node9 = Tree(9)
node5 = Tree(5, [node9])
node6 = Tree(6)
node3 = Tree(3, [node5, node6])
node7 = Tree(7)
node8 = Tree(8)
node4 = Tree(4, [node7, node8])
node2 = Tree(2)
node1 = Tree(1, [node2, node4, node3])

def iterate_child(child):
    global level
    print ' ' * level * 2, child.get_value()
    if child.has_children():
        level += 1
        for s_child in child.get_children():
            iterate_child(s_child)
        level -= 1

level = 1
print node1.get_value()
for child in node1.get_children():
    iterate_child(child)
```

[image: Printing in Depth First Order]

as you can see in the above image, I have iterated through the children of the node1 and recursively iterated over the children of the children node, first, and then processed the second child of the parent node.

Comment: Does this require that the whole tree is known up front?

Comment: No you can start from, any node and do the depth first from that node.