# Python Search Algorithm from Implied Graphs

Tags: python, algorithm, dijkstra, depth-first-search

A little while ago I asked a question ([depth first search algorithm in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33073929/depth-first-search-algorithm-in-python)), which was answered brilliantly by @6502.  It's allowed me to think about this problem more precisely and leads to this follow up question.

In the previous question you have an implied directed tree from a function like this:

```
def neighbors1(node):
    "Returns neighboring nodes in directed tree"
    #some code
    yield node_1
    #some more code
    yield node_2
    #...
    yield node_n
```

and a success criteria function like this:

```
def goal(node):
    "Returns true if node is the end goal and false otherwise"
    if node #meets some goal#:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The first function implies some kind of graph, and depending on the details it may be a tree or a graph with cycles and it may be directed or non-directed.  But suppose that the above implies a directed tree (like the diagram).

[image]

This means that for any node you can find the children nodes, and recursively continue searching down this tree.  Now if you want to get from node A to node H (say), you can use the code from the previous question, passing the neighbors1 function to the search function (reproduced below):

```
def search(start_state, neighbors, goal):
    path = [start_state]

    class PathFound(RuntimeError):
        pass

    def rsearch(x):
        if goal(x):
            raise PathFound
        for y in neighbors(x):
            path.append(y)
            rsearch(y)
            path.pop()

    try:
        rsearch(start_state)
    except PathFound:
        return path

    return None # No path exists
```

So with this you'd simply call

```
search(A,neighbors1,goal)
```

Now (after that long introduction), the question is, what if there are different graphs implied by the neighbor function?

I think if the neighbor function implies a non-directed tree like this:

[image]

then the above may not work, because you could end up with an endless loop where you jump back and forth between e.g. B and F.  However, I think this can be fixed by adding in a simple check to see if you're doubling back:

```
def search(start_state, neighbors, goal):
    path = [start_state]

    class PathFound(RuntimeError):
        pass

    def rsearch(x):
        if goal(x):
            raise PathFound
        for y in neighbors(x):
            if y in path: continue  #New line for undirected graphs
            path.append(y)
            rsearch(y)
            path.pop()

    try:
        rsearch(start_state)
    except PathFound:
        return path

    return None # No path exists
```

Thoughts or comments on the efficiency/effectiveness of the above welcome.

However, the crux of the question, is what if you've got a general graph that is implied by the neighbors function (as follows):

[image: Random Graph]

Is there a similar search function that will allow you to explore shortest paths through that (again just using the neighbors function, rather than *a priori* knowledge of the entire graph).  One option would be to implement dijkstra's algorithm, but I think (though good for finding the best solution), this may be inefficient for finding a good solution to a very large graph.  Is there such a thing as a depth-first search for a graph like this?  Or can dijkstra be implemented in a similar way?  Or what approach would you consider?

I hope the question makes sense and is useful to more people than just me!

Comment: You have identified one of the shortcomings of the basic Depth First Search algorithm - it will get stuck in cycles. One way to circumvent this is to maintain a list of nodes you've already visited, and exclude them from any further exploration. If you don't like that idea, you could try a Breadth First Search, or a different graph traversal algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a rather effective version of Dijkstra's algorithm for finding a path.  Split the search into two lobes, starting one from each terminal node.  Alternate between the two, expanding one depth level on each iteration.

Success is when you add a node to one list that is already on the other: the two searches have met in the middle.

---

Understood: depth-first search, find terminal nodes by examination.  In that case, we need to make a couple of simple alterations:

```
def rsearch(x, found=[]):
    if goal(x):
        raise PathFound
    for y in neighbors(x) and y not in found:
        found.append(y)
        path.insert(0, y)    # switch to depth-first search
        rsearch(y, found)
        path.pop()
```

You can also handle the "found" list accounting by adding a boolean to the node object, marking each node as you touch it.

How does this work for you?  Do you have any way to intuit when you're getting *close* to a goal node?  If so, there could be some heuristic to shorten the search.

Comment: That's a great idea, if you know what the node is to which you're going. Sometimes there are multiple nodes that meet the requirement. However, the question is also about a pythonic way to implement the algorithm given the neighbors function.

Comment: Use the standard alteration: add a new start node whose neighbors are exactly the set of *true* start nodes.  Do likewise for the finish nodes.  Plot a path from start to finish.  I'll get back to the Pythonic part when I have a small block of time.

Comment: ... or are you trying to say that you can't recognize a terminal node until you examine it?  That would change the problem, indeed.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the general problem, but the specific instance that I'm dealing with has the property that there are many possible final nodes, and it's not clear I could easily list them. Easier to determine on examination.